# Java Chat Client.. using .add methood

Tags: java, chat

[image]

```
private javax.swing.JList List_Chat; //name

List_Chat.add("me:" + Text_Chat.getText());

List_Chat.add(Server_Reader.readLine());
```

keep on getting errors have no idea what to do.

Comment: You're going to need to tell us what errors you are getting.  Can you paste a stack trace?

Comment: Error is very clear:

`List_Chat.add()` does not accept `String` as argument. Check out below three language editor suggestions.

Comment: @SimonC, Of course it is compile time error. Because method signature does not exits. How much more do I need to be clearer ? :)

Comment: Ok, he is not even creating object of `List_Chat`. Second error.

Comment: @RaviTrivedi, my bad, completely missed the declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html) if you want to change the content of a JList dynamically.

```
DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
JList list = new JList(listModel);
listModel.addElement("item");
listModel.addElement("another item");
```

Comment: nice catch +1 for this

Comment: I have no idea how to use this, please explain further i am 1st year student with little experience

Comment: @TommyActon [This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) is a good start.

Comment: thank you very much for the answers guys @Siyu Song- Can you guys please give this question a thumbs up so that my question ban can be lifted off